# Content Elements wygwam not displaying

Tags: wygwam, content-elements

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Nothing displays at all. content_elements it the name of my content elements custom field

```
 {content_elements}

  {wygwam}
  {if "{element_name}" == "Content Left Side" OR "{element_name}" == "Content Right Side" }
      <div class="col-lg-6">
         {value}
      </div>
      {if:else}
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            {value}
        </div>
   {/if}
   {wygwam}

{/content_elements}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your closing `wygwam` tag needs a forward slash `/`.

```
{content_elements}

  {wygwam}
  {if "{element_name}" == "Content Left Side" OR "{element_name}" == "Content Right Side" }
      <div class="col-lg-6">
         {value}
      </div>
      {if:else}
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            {value}
        </div>
   {/if}
   {/wygwam}

{/content_elements}
```